# Get particular value from json list use javascript in postman testing

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I am using postman to do API testing.
My response message is

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "Jia",
        "lastName": "Tes",
        "memberId": 745794,
        "branchId": 12442,
        "branchName": "NZ - Clubware Mobile Test Branch 1"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jia",
        "lastName": "Test2",
        "memberId": 745746,
        "branchId": 12442,
        "branchName": "NZ - Clubware Mobile Test Branch 1"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jia",
        "lastName": "Test3",
        "memberId": 745748,
        "branchId": 12443,
        "branchName": "Clubware Mobile Test Branch 2 (Pub)"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jia",
        "lastName": "Test3",
        "memberId": 745745,
        "branchId": 12442,
        "branchName": "NZ - Clubware Mobile Test Branch 1"
    }
]
```

I would like to get "memberId" where "firstName": "Jia","lastName": "Test3" and "branchName": "NZ - Clubware Mobile Test Branch 1"

my current code is like

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log("BODY:" + response[3].memberId);
```

but i don't like use index to locate element in list, how can I do that, thank you guys!!

Comment: try `response.find(e => e.firstName === 'Jia' && e.lastName === 'Test3' && ... etc).memberId` - for more about Array find method [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: @JaromandaX, thank you very much, your suggestion is great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just wanted to check for a specific value, you could use the [_.find()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#find) Lodash function to get the `memberId` value:

```
var user = _.find(pm.response.json(), { 
    firstName: "Jia", 
    lastName: "Test3", 
    branchName: "NZ - Clubware Mobile Test Branch 1" 
})
console.log(user.memberId)
```

[image: Postman Response]

Answer (score 2):

```
var response = [    {
        "firstName": "Jia",
        "lastName": "Tes",
        "memberId": 745794,
        "branchId": 12442,
        "branchName": "NZ - Clubware Mobile Test Branch 1"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jia",
        "lastName": "Test2",
        "memberId": 745746,
        "branchId": 12442,
        "branchName": "NZ - Clubware Mobile Test Branch 1"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jia",
        "lastName": "Test3",
        "memberId": 745748,
        "branchId": 12443,
        "branchName": "Clubware Mobile Test Branch 2 (Pub)"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jia",
        "lastName": "Test3",
        "memberId": 745745,
        "branchId": 12442,
        "branchName": "NZ - Clubware Mobile Test Branch 1"
    }
]; var i;

for(i =0; i <response.length ; i++)
{ 
  if(response[i].firstName == 'Jia' && response[i].lastName == 'Test3' 
     && response[i].branchName == 'NZ - Clubware Mobile Test Branch 1')
  {
    console.log(response[i].memberId);
  }
}
```